# Why I have an error 'cannot read property 'map' of undefined'?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm using React + Redux and I would like to create likes counter, but I have  an error 'cannot read property 'map' of undefined'.

My **Reducer's** code:

```
const initialState = {
    comments: [],
    text: ''
}


case PUT_LIKE: {
        return {
           ...state,
           comments: state.comments.id === action.id ? state.comments.like + 1 : state.comments.like 
      }
}

//before this I have this case for posting comments

 case ADD_COMMENT: {
            let newComment = {
                id: shortid.generate(),
                text: state.text,
                like: 0,
                dislike: 0,
                rating: 0
            }
            return {
                ...state,
                comments: [newComment, ...state.comments],
                text: ''
            }
        }
```

My **Component's** code (deleted some code to make it easier):

```
const ClientFeedback = ({comments,text,postComment,onCommentChange,putLike}) => {

    return (

                      <div className='comments-container'>
                    {comments.map(m => 
                    <div key={m.id} className='comment-container'>
                        <div className='name'>
                            {nameImg}John
                            <span className='product-rating'>{rating}{rating}{rating}</span>
                            <SetDate />
                        </div>
                        <div className='text-comment'>
                            <span onClick={putLike} className='like'>{like}{m.like}</span>
                            <span className='dislike'>{dislike}{m.dislike}</span>
                            <div className='text'>{m.text}</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>)}
                </div>
    )
}
```

**Container**

```
class FeedbackContainer extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <ClientFeedback {...this.props}/>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    comments: state.feedbackReducer.comments,
    text: state.feedbackReducer.text
}) 

export default compose(connect(mapStateToProps,{postComment,onCommentChange,putLike})(FeedbackContainer))
```

**Action code**:

```
export const putLike = (id) => ({type: 'PUT_LIKE', id})
```

[image]

sorry but this annoying:
(
It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details

It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details)

Comment: Are you connecting the component to the redux store?

Comment: @EhsanMahmud Yep.

Comment: Can you provide the whole code?

Comment: comments === undefined

Comment: @DigitalJedi but when I added comment, It shows on the page, so comments can't be undefined...

Comment: @EhsanMahmud Container's component?

Comment: Also, your PUT_LIKE is not correct. That could also be the reason. Did you have a working `comments` before?

Comment: Yes @БогданЧубко

Comment: @EhsanMahmud added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are setting comments incorrectly on PUT_LIKE action. You need to map over the comments and set update the specific comments like value

```
case PUT_LIKE: {
        return {
           ...state,
           comments: state.comments.map(comments => comments.id === action.id ? 
          ({...comments, like: comments.like + 1}) : comments) 
      }
}
```

Comment: Do you still receive the same error? Can you log `state.feedbackReducer` in mapStateToProps and check its value

Comment: What do you mean by nothing happens? Does the comments not render or the like value not update

Comment: I'm using Redux Dev Tool for Chrome, so I can see changes in my state, when I'm using your code - state are equal and nothing changes.

Comment: When are the states equal. Also could you share a screenshot. Also can you see action.id being logged in the reducer and ensure it is present in state

Comment: Ok, let me one minute.

Comment: By the way, in console i have this error: index.js:1 Warning: This synthetic event is reused for performance reasons. If you're seeing this, you're accessing the property `buttons` on a released/nullified synthetic event.

Comment: That means the issue is where you call `putLike` in your component

Comment: Added screenshot

Comment: `<span onClick={() => putLike(m.id)} className='like'>{like}{m.like}</span>` Use this. Note the usage of putLike. Previously you were passing event instead of id

Answer (score 1):

Your reducer should do something like this:

```
case PUT_LIKE: {
        return {
           ...state,
           comments: state.comments.map(comment=>comment.id === action.id ? {...comment, like: comment.like+1} : comment)
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this code snippet cause err.

```js
case PUT_LIKE: {
        return {
           ...state,
           comments: state.comments.id === action.id ? state.comments.like + 1 : state.comments.like 
      }
}
```

You should try:

```js
case PUT_LIKE: {
        return {
           ...state,
           comments: state.comments.map(comment => {
              if(comment.id === action.id) return {...comment, like: comment.like + 1}
              return comment 
           })
      }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, i've updated my answer, I must be if(comment.id === action.id), not if (state.comments.id === action.id).

Comment: @БогданЧубко Please, Could you show me the action code of PUT_LIKE action?

Comment: @БогданЧубко Have you received comments data in ClientFeedback component. If you have, please show me comments data. is it an array?